# Test file existence in Bash

Tags: bash, file, shell, testing

I want to test existence of a file using a Bash script of but get "no file exists..." message even if the file ACTUALLY exists:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Usage : myscript.sh AAAAMMJJ
# where AAAAMMJJ is the argument passed to the script  

d_date=$1

# No accurate content here...
# $d_date value is 20160708
# $d_year value is 2016
# $d_month value is 07
# $d_day value is 08

# Directory path
p_path="/home/user/mydir/${year}"

# Filename is something like: my-file_20160708z.html
f_file="${$p_path}/my-file_${d_date}z.html"

# Testing if file exists
[ ! -f "${f_file}" ] && echo "File OK" || echo "no file..."
```

What is the proper way to test file existence with this kind of construct? This works perfectly with another file (".txt" file).

Comment: Note: No luck either using -e instead of -f... I suspect that I'm maybe doing something wrong regarding variable expansion here.

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: @Cyrus: '$d_date instead' of 'd_date' was a typo, thanks. But quoting "$1" give me same result

Comment: cat '/home/user/mydir/2015/my-file_20160708z.html' is ok as I get file content printing into shell

Comment: You appear to have the test backward. `[ ! -f somefile ]` succeeds if the file *does not* exist.

Comment: @GordonDavisson: You're right. Correct construct would be the opposite: 
[ -f "${f_file}" ] && echo "File OK" || echo "no file..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote:

```bash
# Testing if file exists
[ ! -f "${f_file}" ] && echo "File OK" || echo "no file..."
```

What you should have written:

```bash
# Testing if file exists
[ -f "${f_file}" ] && echo "File OK" || echo "no file..."
```

### Explanation

`man test`:

> ( EXPRESSION )
>
> EXPRESSION is true
>
> ! EXPRESSION
>
> EXPRESSION is false

So when you write just an expression, success means true.

> -f FILE
>
> FILE exists and is a regular file

So, if you wanted to test a file exists, you wouldn't negate the `-f` test by putting a `!`, that would do the opposite.

Comment: @GordonDavisson answered first but answer from user454038 even if it is basically a reference to the man page is more educationnal for other users.